# CORS error depending on an image parameters setting order

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, cors

I'm using a canvas to display an image and get info on a specific portion of that image using getImageData(). Depending the order in which I set the image parameters, it works or not.

The method is called with `onload` on the document body. Here is the code:

```
function draw() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  if (canvas.getContext) {
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var img = new Image();

    img.src = "url_to_image";
    img.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;
    ctx.drawImage( img, 0, 0 );
    var data = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d').getImageData( 310, 320, 1, 1 ).data
  }
}
```

This triggers the following crossOrigin error:

```
Cross-origin image load denied by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy.
```

The server from which I get back the image is configured to set me back an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*` response header with the image.

However, everything works just fine if I just set the `img.crossOrigin` before the `image.src` doing :

```
img.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
img.src = "url_to_image";
```

This seems very peculiar to me. Anybody have an idea of what is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**.crossOrigin must come before .src**

That's because .src actually starts the download.

The browser must know if anonymous access is allowed when it starts the download or it will default to not allowing cross origin access.

Cross Origin sharing is almost fully supported in modern browsers (FF,Chrome,Safari,Opera,Android).  The mini version of Opera is the only major non-supporting browser.

And, as you've discovered, the server delivering the data must be configured to send appropriate headers to let the browser know that cross sharing is allowed.